# COCOA PODS install

Tags: ios, xcode, git, cocoapods

I have tried everything, from every other post, and even created a github account.. create a repository.. named it something random, as they suggested, and plugged that into the terminal.. I'm new at this, so if you can break it down to barney terms.. I'm lost, and cant go on further in my class until I have Cocoapods installed.  this is it;

```
Alexanders-MacBook-Air:~ alex_katona$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.5.3
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.5.3
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 4 seconds
1 gem installed
Alexanders-MacBook-Air:~ alex_katona$ pod setup
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
  $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master --progress
  Cloning into 'master'...
```

**** HERE ****

```
 fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/': LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master --progress
Cloning into 'master'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/': LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
```

Comment: May you format the code a little so we can better understand the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
cd ~/.cocoapods/repos/
git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
```

This either works or at least should show a network connection problem.

Comment: I will update this comment and post the results, thank you

Comment: fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
Alexanders-MacBook-Air:repos alex_katona$ cd ~/.cocoapods/repos/
Alexanders-MacBook-Air:repos alex_katona$ git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
Cloning into 'master'...
remote: Counting objects: 2253267, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (246/246), done.
remote: Total 2253267 (delta 109), reused 35 (delta 35), pack-reused 2252978
Receiving objects: 100% (2253267/2253267), 550.18 MiB | 87.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1292292/1292292), done repos alex_katona$ be

Comment: it shows some failures.. but still finished.. got further than I've been I think... the percent for the 2253267/2253267 took quite awhile but did build to 100% - and everything is still in green.. at the end it says " Alexander - macbook - air : Repos alex_katona$ be     \\ now I dont know what to type after "be"

Comment: It is normal that it takes quite some time resolving deltas. But if it says 100% done, it should have worked. What happens now if you try `pod setup`? Does it say `Setup completed`?

Comment: yes! last lines read; 
$ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/alex_katona/.cocoapods/repos/master reset --hard
  origin/master
  HEAD is now at fe4741f3fc5 [Add] PWMapKitBeta 3.4.1.21
Setup completed   THANK YOU VERY MUCH